# ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I know this question appears several times. But didn't found solution for my app. I'm coding a function to color user avatars based on their name initials.

```
color = this.hashStringToColor(id);
```

this returns a color. then i push it into an array.

```
this.colorsByUser.push({
     color: color,
     id: id
});
```

this array is declared at the beginning in this way:

```
colorsByUser: IProfileColors[] = [];
```

IProfileColors is an interface and contains just color and id. As you see, nothing special is here but i have this weird error that i infer that means i cannot add nothing to the array. Is the first time i face it. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try add to constructor your initialization `this.colorsByUser = [];` and in the declaration use `colorsByUser: any[]` and a testing object in ngOnInit().

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 

You haven't indicated what code is being called when the error in the title is returned.

The message indicates you're trying to push to an object, so it's the code you AREN'T sharing that probably contains the issue.

Comment: I agree with previous comments. The issue is more likely somewhere else, or  in hashStringToColor?